# How to know all memory an object occupy when the object have some dynamic allocated memory?

Tags: c++

For example:
    How to know how many memory a std::string object occupy, including the memory allocated in the heap used by std::string?

According to the answers below:
It seems there is no genreral solution, I have to do it by the specific implementation.

Comment: You can't.  What if two objects refer to the same block of memory? What about a cyclic linked-list? How do you track allocations?

Comment: Depends on the implementation - what is the specific problem?

Comment: @SLaks There is no general answer, but it's a bit harsh to say "you can't".

Comment: @Ed heal The problem is I want to estimate the average memory use by the object which have dynamic allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the data structured used, and may depend on how it is implemented by your compiler. In the case of `std::string`, the `capacity` function returns the number of elements currently allocated in its internal buffer. In this case, as `char` has size 1, it is effectively the number of bytes dynamically allocated by the string object.

`sizeof (std::string)` returns the number of bytes contained in just the string class, which is constant for all string objects, but doesn't include the dynamic memory managed by the string object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe :sizeof(mystring)+mystring.size()*sizeof(char)